# .htaccess mod rewrite and MAMP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

having issues with what i think is linked to the mod rewrite in mamp.

The rewrite works fine on the live server, but im working locally with MAMP and getting issues.

The problem is linked to this:

I rewrite the following URL:

```
http://localhost/BuildSanctuary-Dev/viewbuild/64/three-fiddy-z/1
```

That should rewrite as:

```
http://localhost/BuildSanctuary-Dev/viewbuild.php?id=64&title=three-fiddy-z&page=1
```

The issue is that i get a 404 for page not found.

```
The requested URL /viewbuild.php was not found on this server.
```

Which it clearly is... but if i visit just /viewbuild.php it works fine.

The rewrite in the .htaccess is:

```
RewriteRule ^viewbuild/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /viewbuild.php?id=$1&title=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Any ideas? I have done the research and everything in the apache conf is showing as Allowing All...

Thanks.

Comment: Does `BioldSanctuary-Dev/` actually exist as a directory? What directory does this .htaccess reside in? `/viewbuild.php` targets the web document root, not the directory...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rewriterule redirects to `/viewbuild.php` and not `/BuildSanctuary-Dev/viewbuild.php`:

```
RewriteRule ^viewbuild/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /BuildSanctuary-Dev/viewbuild.php?id=$1&title=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

A mabye better variant would be to put the .htaccess into the `/BuildSanctuary-Dev/` folder and use a relative path as redirect:

```
RewriteBase /BuildSanctuary-Dev
RewriteRule ^viewbuild/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ viewbuild.php?id=$1&title=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Ah yes, forgot about the extra folder for the local site. Many thanks!