# Configure MAMP to treat each directory in Htdocs as Root in Apache mod_redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp

The issue is that when using MAMP for local development, the `.htaccess` file needs to differ in that the `RewriteBase` needs to specify the subdirectory for the specific site (as shown [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25435621/htaccess-mod-rewrite-and-mamp)).

Is there a way to configure MAMP `MAMP/conf/apachehttpd.conf` so that each virtual site gets it's own "root"?

**UPDATE**

After getting a clue about Virtual Hosts:

Have updated `/etc/hosts` file to include:

```
127.0.0.1       ClientSite.localhost
```

Uncommented the line:

```
`#Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
```

in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`.

There is a directory called `ClientSite` in `/Users/myname/Sites/`.

This is the `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` content:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/myname/Sites/%0

    RewriteLogLevel 3
    RewriteLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/rewrite.log"

    <Directory /Users/myname/Sites>
       Options All
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restarted the MAMP servers (and even ran `dscacheutil -flushcache`).

When browser is pointed to `ClientSite.localhost` it returns a `404`: `The requested URL / was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so that each virtual site gets it's own "root"?

You need to use [`VirtualDocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot).

This is how I am using this on my `MAMP` in my `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/admin/htdocs/%0

    RewriteLogLevel 3
    RewriteLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/rewrite.log"

    <Directory /Users/admin/htdocs>
       Options All
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Take note of `VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/admin/htdocs/%0` directive. That makes each virtual site's root as:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/admin/htdocs/localhost
VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/admin/htdocs/dev.localhost
VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/admin/htdocs/client2.localhost
```

etc.

Then simply create a directory within `/Users/admin/htdocs/` for each site named as above, like:

```
dev.localhost
client2.localhost
```

Remove (or rename) any `.htaccess` files during the process - and once websites confirmed to be accessible via url like: `http://client2.localhost`, `.htaccess` files should behave as expected.

Also be sure that in the `/etc/hosts` file, there's an entry like:

```
127.0.0.1    client2.localhost
```

for each URL in question.

Comment: Does this change the site url from `localhost:8888/subdir` to something else? I've updated the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file accordingly, restarted the server and removed the subdirectory from the `.htaccess` file, but Apache is again redirecting to the `htdocs` directory. Am I missing a setting?

Comment: Don't know how you're getting this **Apache is again redirecting to the htdocs directory** Above config is to set right document root not for redirecting. Make sure you remove all rules and .htaccess when you test this. Also show your `VirtualHost` config in question.

Comment: I've updated the question. This has been an insightful experience so far. All .htaccess files have been removed.

Comment: Does `/Users/myname/Sites/ClientSite.localhost` directory exist? And that directory should also have some index file like `index.html` or `index.php`

Comment: No! The directories were named without the `.localhost`. I had thought that was somehow getting added 'virtually'. I am going to test the .htaccess and report back but looking good!

Comment: perfect! i submitted some of the specifics to your answer as an edit.