# .htaccess redirect all urls to public/index.php without backslash on localhost

Tags: php, .htaccess, localhost

#### Background

I'm creating a time tracking app with PHP on my localhost (MAMP). The app structure is as follows

- `htdocs/time-tracker/public/index.php`

#### Issue

No matter how many configurations I try, I can't seem to avoid some sort of weird glitch with the URL.

#### What I need

I want the following result. When I visit the url `127.0.0.1:8888/time-tracker` on my local machine, I trigger the php app, routing all requests through the `htdocs/time-tracker/public/index.php`. Preferably without a trailing slash, but priority is just to get the app to work.

#### My current .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /time-tracker/
RewriteRule ^public\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /public [L]
```

## Updates

#### 1. $_GET parameters change outcome

For some reason `http://127.0.0.1:8888/time-tracker?debug=true` and `http://127.0.0.1:8888/time-tracker` get me different results.

- `http://127.0.0.1:8888/time-tracker?debug=true` results in a redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/public`
- `http://127.0.0.1:8888/time-tracker` results in a redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/Users/etc/etc/htdocs/time-tracker/public`

Neither of these results are what I want.

#### 2. Partially working

This `.htaccess` file has gotten my redirects to work whenever I put something in the $_GET

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php [L]
```

For example, `127.0.0.1:8888/time-tracker/?test=test` works while `127.0.0.1:8888/time-tracker/` still redirects to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/Users/etc/etc/htdocs/time-tracker/public`

#### 3. Not redirecting properly on root

The redirects works on all paths except for the root path. For example, `127.0.0.1:8888/time-tracker/test` and `127.0.0.1:8888/time-tracker/?test=test` both work, just not `127.0.0.1:8888/time-tracker/`

I don't know why my regex won't pick this up. Here is my code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* public/index.php [L]
```

#### 4. Seeing an empty path name

I've tracked it down to one last issue: empty paths don't register with the redirect.

```
# Settings
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

# Rules
RewriteBase /time-tracker/public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*|x) index.php?/var=$1 [L]
```

For some reason, it just can't catch the redirect if the path is empty.

#### 5. Close enough solution

This is the best I got. This is actually working, but I couldn't fix the trailing slash issue.

```
# Settings
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite
RewriteBase /time-tracker/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?/var=$1 [L]
```

Hopefully somebody can come solve the trailing slash directory root issue or at least confirm that it is impossible. At this point, the correct answer goes to anyone who can explain my mistakes and make this into a helpful post.

Answer (score 1):

Try this right after RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried something similar before. The error with this method is that it redirects me to `127.0.0.1:8888/Users/ect/ect/htdocs/time-tracker/public`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Put your .htaccess file in the time-tracker folder

```
  RewriteOptions inherit
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on 
     RewriteBase /time-tracker/public/
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Didn't work. I triggered the same error as my most recent .htaccess script. It seems like there might be something weird and specific with my system. I'm running this on MAMP localhost, and most things that _should_ work aren't...

Comment: Sorry man I'm not very familiar with MAMP. but this link could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176078/configure-mamp-to-treat-each-directory-in-htdocs-as-root-in-apache-mod-redirect